# Sublime Text: overlay cannot match file name with @

Tags: sublimetext3, overlay, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have a file named `image@3x.png`, which have a `@` in file name.

and I use `cmd + p` to open the `overlay`, then I input `image`,
the result shows all files which has `image` in it,
then I input `@` to make my whole input become `image@`,
and then, the whole result is **gone**.

the `@3x` or `@2x` comes from zeplin, means the size of image,
so I prefer not to change the name of file to fit ST.

Can any one help?

btw,
I know if I input `@` in the beginning of `overlay` will make it search `function definition` in current file.
I have no idea does it associate with it or not?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no way to "escape" the `@` character in Goto Anything, so my suggestion is just not to type it. You could search for `image x` and it would show `image@3x.png` as a possible result, because it uses fuzzy matching.

Comment: Okay, I guess that's the most acceptable work-around solution, thanks